# How to return from a .map looping to fetch data from an aPI

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, array.prototype.map

I am trying to loop over an array of URLs and go fetch the data at that URL's endpoint then store it as JSON objects in an array (allData). When I run my code and check what's in allData it is continuously an array of nulls. This tells me I'm not returning correctly from the .map? How do I do that given the data is coming from an async function. Here's my code below. Thanks

```
const allData = urls.map((url)=>{
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {return data})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

Comment: You've got multiple issues going on here, like not returning anything in the map function, but there are already solutions to exactly this problem. I've linked to one of them above, but if you prefer a longer-format blog article then check this out: https://dev.to/nyagarcia/array-map-async-await-2cif

Comment: Both very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the promises in the array to be resolved and return the promise in the .map function

```js
const urls = ['https://mocki.io/v1/d4867d8b-b5d5-4a48-a4ab-79131b5809b8', 'https://mocki.io/v1/d4867d8b-b5d5-4a48-a4ab-79131b5809b8']
const allData = urls.map((url)=>{
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {return data})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
})   
Promise.all(allData).then(console.log)
```

Comment: That solved it. Thanks

Comment: Great happy to help. Make sure to mark the question as resolved :)